# Variable scoping of "for i in range(XX)" in Python

Tags: python, variables, scoping

This is a exercise for Python, and I am confused about the variable scoping in Python.

> "Return True if the given string contains an appearance of "xyz" where
>   the xyz is not directly preceeded by a period (.). So "xxyz" counts
>   but "x.xyz" does not.
>
> xyz_there('abcxyz') → True
>   xyz_there('abc.xyz')→ False 
>   xyz_there('xyz.abc') → True"

This is my answer:

```
def xyz_there(str):
   for i in range(len(str)-2):
        if str[i]=='.':
           i+=1
           continue
        elif str[i:i+3]=='xyz':
           return True
   return False
```

And it is wrong. `xyz_there('abc.xyz') → False` will always return `True`. Because the variable `i` will always be 0,1,2.... And the `i+=1` doesn't mean anything.
Why???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that you can't change the value of `i`.  You can.  The trick here is that you are iterating over the contents of the return value of `range`.  Each time the loop resets you get the next value from that iterable, it does not increment the value of `i` to progress the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to use a for loop?  This would be a great place for a regular expression.  I've modified the example below so I'm not just giving you the answer...  Instead of looking for "xyz", I'm looking for "hello".  And I'm also trying to avoid seeing a "?" before that "hello".

```
import re
def hello_there(str):
    if re.match("(.*[^\?])?hello.*", str):
        return True
    return False
```

The regex pattern consists of:

- `.*` - any number of non-newline characters at the beginning of the string;
- `[^\?]` - disallowing `^` a(n escaped) question mark `\?` before everything that follows;
- `hello` - ensuring that `hello` will make an appearance;
- `.*` - and ending in any number of other characters.

re.match will return a MatchObject that resolves to a boolean value of True, so it can be used as the condition in the if statement.

```
>>> hello_there("foohellobar")
True
>>> hello_there("foo?hellobar")
False
>>> hello_there("foohello?bar")
True
```

Comment: While valid, this is overkill for the question.  It also doesn't actually answer the question, which was "Why can't I modify the value of `i` in my `for` loop?".

Comment: Oh... sorry, I wasn't trying to give an overkill answer.  You had already explained why i wasn't functioning as he expected.  Just trying to show that there might be a cleaner way of implementing xyz_there.

Comment: No problem.  I did not down vote, just commented.  I'd also guess (though I can't guarantee it) that the exercise is on a site like codingbat.com where you can't import modules for your solutions.  All good. :)

Comment: Wow,thanks.I was just a beginner.Thanks for dbustad to giving another way to solve this problem.But g.d.d.c's answer really cleared up my confusion....

Answer (score 0):

simplest answer is:

```
def xyz_there(str):
    for i in range(len(str)-2):
        if str[i:i+3] == "xyz" and str[i-1] != ".":
            return True
    return False
```